# Steric effect of t-butyl group on SN1 on a cyclohexane ring

Tags: organic-chemistry, nucleophilic-substitution, cyclohexane

This is a question from [GRB Kota Question Bank Organic Chemistry](https://www.amazon.in/Question-Organic-Chemistry-2019-2020-Examination/dp/9388599632), Chapter 3, Reasoning type, Q. 4:

> **Assertion:** *trans*-1-*t*-butyl-4-chlorocyclohexane is less reactive than *cis*-1-*t*-butyl-4-chlorocyclohexane towards an S<sub>N</sub>1 reaction.
>
> **Reason:** More the steric factor near the leaving group, the higher the leaving group tendency.

The answer given is:

> Both the assertion and reason is correct and the reason is the correct explanation for the assertion.

The answer given feels wrong.

My reasoning for saying so is because the rate determining step in an S<sub>N</sub>1 is the formation of a carbocation. Due to this, the steric effect seems irrelevant. However, when the intermediate is same for both compounds undergoing substitution, I assume that the compound having greater stability would be less reactive since the threshold energy required would be greater.

Using the above statement, we can say that *trans*-1-*t*-butyl-4-chlorocyclohexane would be less reactive since both the groups are in equatorial position making it more stable whereas in its *cis*-isomer the *t*-butyl group would be equatorial whereas the chloride group would be axial.

Due to this, I presume that the assertion is correct. However, the reason seems vague as it does not mention whether the reaction taking place is S<sub>N</sub>1 or S<sub>N</sub>2 since this could change with respect to the reaction involved.

Is there anything wrong with my above reasoning? Can the validity of the reason be proved/disproved beyond doubt?

Comment: Two cyclohexane rings with no leaving groups are not reactive towards substitution.

Comment: @Zhe, I have rectified the issue.. It was chloride and not methyl.

Comment: An SN1 reaction will occur faster when the solvent is able to solvate the cation formed,thus compensating for the energy required in breaking the carbon-leaving group bond. Steric hindrance will inhibit this solvation. Does this hint help in answering your question?

Comment: @YusufHasan So, the reason is correct.. Thanks for that. However how does this make it the correct explanation?

Comment: Also, I am pretty sure that the "steric factor" as stated in the question is a textbook erratum: that term generally refers to the ratio between the experimental value of the rate constant and the one predicted by collision theory as stated [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steric_factor#:~:text=Also%20called%20the%20probability%20factor,most%20often%20less%20than%20unity.). I guess they meant to say steric hindrance

Comment: Also, the t-butyl group is in the farthest possible position, how does it affect it in this case? Or is the size so large that it is affected?

Comment: In the cis isomer, the solvation of the cation will be somewhat sterically inhibited as compared to the trans isomer. Therefore,theoretically, the trans isomer should be more susceptible to the rate-determining step(RDS) of the SN1 reaction(i.e. the formation of carbocation) than the cis isomer, and hence show a greater percentage of the SN1 reaction than the cis one

Comment: The t butyl group might be big enough to disrupt the solvation sheath that could have been formed over the cation even when it is that far away. Anyway,since this is a relative comparison,we are only interested in seeing how each factor plays out with respect to each other. The absolute percentage of the SN1 reaction doesn't matter as such here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110809/discussion-between-safdar-and-yusuf-hasan).

Comment: @YusufHasan: I _doubt_ that solvation would matter, by seeing the structure of [cis](https://www.chemsrc.com/en/cas/13131-74-3_883654.html) and [trans](https://www.chemsrc.com/en/cas/13145-48-7_1204199.html) forms of 1-t-butyl-4-methylcyclohexane. As, the t-butyl group is on same side, so I think intermediate would be identical. And, therefore I prefer to look steric factors.

Comment: @RahulVerma I am talking about the solvation which would be present even before the C-Cl bond is broken. The breaking of the C-Cl bond doesn't happen on it's own; the Cl of the C-Cl bond is solvated by the positive end of the polar protic solvent,and these weak bonds which are formed b/w the solvent and the leaving group will provide the energy to ultimately break the C-Cl bond itself. This solvation will definitely be affected by the fact that whether the butyl is on the same or opposite side as the C-Cl. Anyway, the steric factor argument presented by the book doesn't make sense on it's own

Comment: ...The presence of a sterically larger group can maybe increase the rotation barriers,and therefore reduce the number of conformers available,but I don't think it can have such a drastic effect so as to somehow weaken the C-Cl bond and allow the leaving group to leave on it's own accord

Comment: Hmm... I get it now. I too think that the reason in wrong.

Comment: @YusufHasan Can you post a definitive answer on this.. seems as though the question is pretty confusing.

Comment: @Safdar I would say that Zhe's answer provides the complete reasoning comprehensively. I myself had forgotten about Hammond's postulate and so was trying to answer this using indirect methods. As a final note, I feel that the book has got the correct answer with a somewhat incomplete explanation, as it is not immediately obvious why steric hindrance might lead to a quicker reaction(which is why I made a mistake in understanding it ). I would label the assertion as "correct", and the reasoning as "partially correct, but more elaboration is required, especially a reference to Hammon's postulate"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would argue that the reasoning makes sense.

There are some important things to discuss here.

The cis isomer ($C$) and the trans isomer ($T$) will both react via the same carbocation intermediate. This means the energies of the intermediate are the same. Chloride has an A-value of [0.43](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_value#Table_of_A-Values), so $C$ is higher in energy than $T$. Since the formation of cation is endothermic, we may invoke the Hammond Postulate: the first step has a late transition state that structurally looks like the intermediate and is similar to it in energy. Finally, we conclude that the transition state for the reaction from $C$ has a lower barrier and thus a faster reaction.

[image: reaction coordinate diagram]

Now, there is no way to "prove" that this or any other rationale is correct. There is no way to prove any model is correct. That's not how science works. You can only have consistent models that are good enough for now. They may even be "right," but you will never know. On the other hand, you could a reject the model based on inconsistency with experimental evidence, but there's no contradictory experimental evidence here.